# Lightning Component attribute get and set

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I am working to implement lightning data table. I have a requirement where I have to add row-level actions on the table. The action will open a modal with details of the selected row. The user can edit these details. However, when the user selects the Cancel button in the modal, the changes are still getting saved to the table row.

```
var row = event.getParam('row');

component.set("v.productSelectedRow", row);

//productSelectedRow is attribute
```

changes to productSelectedRow, is causing chnges to original 'row', even if user clicks Cancel button.

How can I prevent this? Is there a way to not deep clone, when doing `component.set("v.productSelectedRow", row)`, so changes to productSelectedRow, do not change 'row'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use Object.assign or the rest parameter to copy the object. Make sure you save the changes back to the original object when the user saves.

```
component.set("v.productSelectedRow", Object.assign({}, row));
```

Note that you have your terminology backwards; "cloning" would not update the row, while just assigning a "reference" will update the row.